# how to start the daemon process ? and unable to change the value of heap object

Tags: android

Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m

How to make the changes in android studio..??

Answer (score 1):

Open your project gradle.properties file and make changes in heap size.

**XX:MaxPermSize=256m is default value and make it XX:MaxPermSize=1024m**

gradle.properties

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Answer (score 0):

From Android Studio documentation ([link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration))

> **Increasing IDE Memory**
>
> By default, the IDE is assigned a maximum of 750 MB. If you have a large project, or if you have a lot of RAM on your system, the IDE will run better if you increase the amount of memory it is allowed to use. To do that, create your own studio.vmoptions override (in the location explained above) and add a line like this:
>
> `-Xmx2048m`
>
> The full set of default JVM arguments are the following, in case you want to override any of the others (such as the start heap size of the MaxPermSize) :defaults in the IDE right
>
> `-Xms128m`
>
> `-Xmx750m`
>
> `-XX:MaxPermSize=350m`
>
> `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m`
>
> `-XX:+UseCompressedOops`